# In R, how can a string be split without using a seperator

Tags: r, split

i am try split method and i want to have the second element of a string containing only 2 elemnts. The size of the string is 2.

examples :

```
string= "AC"
```

result shouldbe a split after the first letter ("A"), that I get :

```
res=    [,1] [,2]
     [1,] "A" "C"
```

I tryed it with split, but I have no idea  how to split after the first element??

Answer (score 5):

`strsplit()` will do what you want (if I understand your Question). You need to split on `""` to split the string on it's elements. Here is an example showing how to do what you want on a vector of strings:

```
strs <- rep("AC", 3) ## your string repeated 3 times
```

next, split each of the three strings

```
sstrs <- strsplit(strs, "")
```

which produces

```
> sstrs
[[1]]
[1] "A" "C"

[[2]]
[1] "A" "C"

[[3]]
[1] "A" "C"
```

This is a list so we can process it with `lapply()` or `sapply()`. We need to subset each element of `sstrs` to select out the second element. Fo this we apply the `[` function:

```
sapply(sstrs, `[`, 2)
```

which produces:

```
> sapply(sstrs, `[`, 2)
[1] "C" "C" "C"
```

If all you have is one string, then

```
strsplit("AC", "")[[1]][2]
```

which gives:

```
> strsplit("AC", "")[[1]][2]
[1] "C"
```

Answer (score 2):

`split` isn't used for this kind of string manipulation. What you're looking for is `strsplit`, which in your case would be used something like this:

```
strsplit(string,"",fixed = TRUE)
```

You may not need `fixed = TRUE`, but it's a habit of mine as I tend to avoid regular expressions. You seem to indicate that you want the result to be something like a matrix. `strsplit` will return a list, so you'll want something like this:

```
strsplit(string,"",fixed = TRUE)[[1]]
```

and then pass the result to `matrix`.

Answer (score 0):

If you sure that it's always two char string (check it by `all(nchar(x)==2)`) and you want only second then you could use `sub` or `substr`:

```
x <- c("ab", "12")
sub(".", "", x)
# [1] "b" "2"
substr(x, 2, 2)
# [1] "b" "2"
```